# Textfieldshouldreturn auto scroll screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I use the code below. As it seems I have 5 uitextfields. Now for some reason when I clicked next, the view actually scrolled down automatically so I could see the textfield I was writing data with the keyboard. I thought this was default.

I added a lot of code in the uiview and added a button linking to another view. Somehow in the middle of that process my uiview lost its "auto-scroll-when-next-is-pressed" mechanism. I tried deleting my button and messed around a bit but couldn't find the problem.

Not sure if I should post the whole class.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (textField == self.firstOne) {
        [self.secondOne becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.secondOne) {
        [self.thirdOne becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.thirdOne) {
        [self.fourthOne becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.fourthOne) {
        [self.fifthOne becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return NO; 
}
```

I also found some content on how to scroll screen programmatic by setting up coordinates. Not very viable in my opinion. I want it to be the way it was "Knowing where to scroll down automatically".

Answer (score 0):

I hope that add the ScrollView in View and next step add the 5 TextField in SubView of the UIScrollView such like as

```
[scrollView addSubView:textField1];
```

Next increase and decrease the scrollview content of set. Such as

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
       [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 230) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason is I added viewWillAppear method when I introduced the new button. That code didn't call the super method, so by just adding 1 line of code the problem was fixed

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // your code
}
```